# Autoload custom exceptions files with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app/ directory I have a folder **services**. To autoload my files in the service folder, I added 'app/services' in my 'config/spring.rb'

```
%w(
  .ruby-version
  .rbenv-vars
  tmp/restart.txt
  tmp/caching-dev.txt
  app/services
).each { |path| Spring.watch(path) }
```

It's work fine. But now, I want to create a sub dir for my custom exceptions (in app/services/errors/). But when I try to add a new line in my spring.rb :

```
%w(
      .ruby-version
      .rbenv-vars
      tmp/restart.txt
      tmp/caching-dev.txt
      app/services
      app/services/errors
    ).each { |path| Spring.watch(path) }
```

It's not working, I got some :

```
NameError:
       uninitialized constant SixError
```

Here my custom error file (app/services/errors/six_error.rb):

```
class SixError < RuntimeError
end

class NilTokenError < SixError
end

class SixRequestFailed < SixError
end

class NoAliasRequestPendingError < SixError
end

class AmountLessThanZeroError < SixError
end

class NilAliasError < SixError
end
```

And this is how I called this :

```
SixError::SixRequestFailed
```

Comment: I think you have to load your files in order, the file with SixError should be loaded first, the rest next. So try changing your loading order  the following,  %w(.ruby-version .rbenv-vars tmp/restart.txt tmp/caching-dev.txt app/services app/services/errors/six_error.rb, app/services/errors)

Comment: what line in the code is it pointing to when it is throwing this error, 'uninitialized constant SixError'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is loading class in subdir with a namespace corresponding to the dirname.
If you have this structure :
-app
--services
---errors
----six_errors.rb

Rails expecting the file `six_errors.rb` to declare class upon the namespace `Errors`.

In your case you should declare all your errors class in a module named `Errors`.

```
module Errors
  class SixError < RuntimeError; end
end
```